# GCC compiling with -pg doesn't produce binary needed for Gprof

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, performance-testing, gprof

I'm running into a little problem and require some assistance. I would like to run gprof on some [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) and [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) hybrid code as a part of my testing. I understand that [Gprof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof) relies on a binary file which is created when you compile GCC (or `mpicc`) with a [-pg](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-pg) switch.

I have tried adding this switch and my compiling succeeds (as in no errors are reported), however, the binary file is not created, but the executable is created as normal. I have also tried doing this on much simpler code, which uses pthreads, with the same result.

Please examine the below and let me hear your thoughts.

```
gcc -pg --std=gnu99 -pthread -Wall -o pthreadsv0 pthreads.c
```

GCC compiling with -pg doesn't produce binary needed for Gprof.

Comment: The gprof information is created when you __execute__ the program __after__ you compile with the `-pg` option.  Try running your program.  (You're profiling (gprof) the execution of the program)

Comment: @lornix, it works! And now that you've mentioned it, I wonder how I didn't think of that. Please add your answer officially so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gprof information is created when you **execute** the program **after** you compile with the `-pg` option. Try running your program. (You're profiling (Gprof) the execution of the program.)

The `-pg` compile option adds the necessary logic to create the profiling information when the program is executed.  Executing the program, several times if desired or needed, allows the 'instrumented' code to write the data describing the logic flow and timing to the `gmon.out` file.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the binary file you mention is in fact the profile data file (`gmon.out`), and it is generated when you run your program (which has to be compiled with the -pg flag).

Just execute your program and see if a `gmon.out` file is there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. It has worked and I'm completely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The problem arose because I was shutting the program's execution with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of a proper exit (closing the GUI window in my case).